# How to perform a reference assign?

Tags: c#

Try not to get too hung up on what I'm doing here, this is just an example:

```
var @string = new RegexTerm("...");
var literal = new RegexTerm("...");
var key = @string | literal;
var dict = new Term();
var value = key | dict;
var kvp = key | value;
var item = key | kvp;
var set = item + !("," + item);
dict = "{" + set + "}";
```

I have a circular relationship. `value` needs `dict` to be defined, and `dict` needs `value` to be defined.

So what I've done is initialized `dict` to some placeholder Term so that I can use it in the following assignment, and then I give it it's real value later on.

The problem is that now `value` no longer refers to the same object as defined on the last line. I essentially want to re-assign `dict` without creating a new object.

Is there any way to do this without adding a setter? This would require me to create a public parameterless constructor on my `AndTerm` and then add a `Set` method, which just isn't as pretty, and allows you to construct invalid objects.

Or is there some magical way of reassigning `dict` to point to a new object and update all existing references? Apparently I'm not allowed to overload the `=` operator.

---

Came up with one solution. I added an extra Term called a `ProxyTerm`:

```
var dict = new ProxyTerm();
var value = key | dict;
...
dict.Term = "{" + set + "}";
```

This allows me to keep the base `Term` class as abstract, and then I don't need to expose any private variables or add any setters.

Comment: Where do those Term types come from?

Comment: @phoog: What do you mean? I wrote them; they're not from an existing library.

Comment: That's what I meant.  You need some kind of closure over the variable. Perhaps you could achieve that with lambda expressions.

Comment: What does bang mean when applied to a string?

Comment: @RitchMelton: It's not applied to a string, it's applied to a `Term`. I've defined it to mean "zero or more". Unfortunately there's no unary asterisk.

Comment: Is value a term or a RegexTerm? What does it mean to overload bitwise or '|'? Why does dict take a string even though its a term?

Comment: @phoog: I'm not sure how lambdas would help with that...can you elaborate?

Comment: @RitchMelton: I said not to get hung up on what I'm doing ;) The point here is not my example... I simply want to know if there's a way we can perform an assignment without creating a new object.

Comment: @Mark I'm not hung up. I'm confused by it. I still don't get your question and, without trying to be critical, its muddled by the contextual changes you've made to the standard operators.

Comment: @RitchMelton: `value` is an `OrTerm`. When two terms are `|`'d they become an `OrTerm` (which just holds references to the 2 terms), when they're `+`d they become an `AndTerm`. Strings are implicitly cast to `StringTerms` which extend the base `Term` class like everything else. This allows me to define grammars in a very compact way similar to [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Comment: @RitchMelton: Hopefully now you can see the circular relationship. It's essentially building a tree of terms internally.

Comment: @Mark - Yea, I see it. I'm curious to see what somebody way smarter than me can give you for an answer, while respecting your constraints.

Comment: @Mark Lambdas would force the compiler to do something similar to the solution you came up with, but it would be more opaque and slightly more complicated, so your solution is probably better.  In brief, if you have a local variable `int x = 0;`, and a lambda expression `Action<int> y = () => x;` then calling the delegate created from the lambda will give you the value of x *at the time of the call*, not its value *at the time of the delegate's creation.*

Comment: @phoog: I get that, but I want to do it the other way around, don't I? When I declare `dict` I basically don't know the value of `x` yet...it isn't until later that I do. So in that sense, I want `value` to refer to a future variable, not the one defined at present.

Comment: @Mark: in that case, you'd need a term like your ProxyTerm that takes a delegate; you'd declare `Term dict = null;` and build your object graph using the lambda, and then reassign `dict`.  So the object graph has a reference to the lambda, which returns dict, and then you reassign dict.  Like I said, it's more complicated and opaque than the solution you came up with.  The pattern is useful, though, for declaring recursive lambdas.

Comment: @phoog: Yeah...sounds like another layer of indirection that isn't useful here. Oh wells. Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution would be to code against an interface or an abstract base and use a proxy pattern.

```
class ProxyTerm : ITerm {

     ITerm Reference { get; set; }

     ITerm.SomeMethod() {
          Reference.SomeMethod();
     }

}
```

This way you'll be able to plug in the real reference afterwards.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I came up with (did you read my addendum first?). Didn't know it was an official pattern though.

Comment: Haha, I somehow skipped your addendum the first time I read it and decided not to comment on it afterwards. D'oh. :) Sorry for that! :)